# How to save object with many-to-many mapping with extra column?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How can I save object with many to many mapping with extra column? Special column is "approval". With many-to-many annotation I only called setUsersDocuments(users) and it was working ok... how can I make it work with extra columns?

Document

```
@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document")
    private List<UsersDocuments> documentsForUsers;
```

User class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UsersDocuments> usersDocuments;
```

PK

```
@Embeddable
public class UserDocumentsId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long user;

    @Column(name="document_id")
    private long document;
```

MANY-TO-MANY table

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="users_documents")
public class UsersDocuments {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserDocumentsId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("document")
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
    private Document document;

    @Column(name="approval")
    private boolean approval;
```

Saving document

```
Document document = new Document(title, desc);
        document.setUploadDatetime(new Date());
        document.setUser(user.get());

        List<User> users = userService.getUsersByRoles(roles);

//        document.setDocumentsForUsers(users); THIS WAS WHEN USING ONLY MANY TO MANY ANNOTATION
        
        documentService.saveDocument(document);
```

EDIT: Unsuccesfull saving object - document.getDocumentsForUsers().add(userDocuments) NULL.

```
Optional<User> user = userService.getUserByEmail(createdBy);
        Document document = new Document(title, desc);
        document.setUploadDatetime(new Date());
        document.setUser(user.get());

        List<User> users = userService.getUsersByRoles(roles);

        for(User userx : users){
            UsersDocuments userDocuments = new UsersDocuments();
            UserDocumentsId id = new UserDocumentsId();

            // Construct the Id with user and document
            id.setUser(userx.getId());
            id.setDocument(document.getId());

            userDocuments.setId(id);
            userDocuments.setApproval(true);

            // This is very important for saving and cascading to work.
            document.getDocumentsForUsers().add(userDocuments);
        }

        documentService.saveDocument(document);
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.patrikmaryska.bc_prace.bc_prace.controller.DocumentController.getDocumentFromClient(DocumentController.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.patrikmaryska.bc_prace.bc_prace.controller.DocumentController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3a9de86b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.patrikmaryska.bc_prace.bc_prace.controller.DocumentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b46e5706.getDocumentFromClient(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at com.patrikmaryska.bc_prace.bc_prace.config.CorsConfig.doFilter(CorsConfig.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Show the mapping in which you define your manytomany dependency

Comment: You already have `UsersDocuments` which seems to be an entity. What's the problem with adding an extra property/column there?

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski done. Sorry, I copied bad table. Now it should be ok.

Comment: @Thomas It is not a problem to add extra column, problem is to save it. I dont know how to save it to the database...

Comment: Well, you somehow create a `UsersDocuments` entity when saving a new document or a new relation to a user. Assuming `document.setDocumentsForUsers(users);` did that you could set the additional data there. In any case you'd need to differentiate between creating and saving the `UserDocuments` in general and addition additional data to that entity. You're asking about the latter but I have the feeling that you're actually having problems with the former. If you don't have problems with saving `UserDocuments` in general then I don't understand your problem - could you elaborate?

Comment: setDocumentsForUsers(users) works for many-to-many annotation. But i need to save object with many-to-many mapping with additional column. So it cannot be done the same way. :(

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In Document entity add cascading to the UserDocuments relation:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UsersDocuments> usersDocuments;
```

**2)** You need to set-up your entities differently:

```
Document document = new Document(title, desc);
document.setUploadDatetime(new Date());

List<User> users = userService.getUsersByRoles(roles);

for(Use user: users){
    UserDocuments userDocuments = new UserDocuments();
    UserDocumentsId id = new UserDocumentsId();

    // Construct the Id with user and document
    id.setUser(user);
    id.setDocument(document);

    userDocuments.setDocumentsId(id);
    userDocuments.setActivtity(true);

    // This is very important for saving and cascading to work.
    document.getUserDocuments().add(userDocuments);
}

documentService.saveDocument(document);
```

Comment: I edited my post with my version of saving object according to your answer. It throws NULL pointer exception...

Comment: just set that list to new ArrayList in constructor for example or directly on the field..

Comment: which list do you mean? I am not really sure, what you mean right now... :(

Comment: document.getDocumentsForUsers()

Comment: I ve done this: in Document() constructor I have: documentsForUsers = new ArrayList<>(); - but the same problem :(

Comment: you need to add the stack trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196521/discussion-between-arthemoon-and-maciej-kowalski).